# Commerce: Hide "Save and Add Another" button when saving new product

Tags: 7, forms, commerce

I'm trying to hide the "Save and Add Another" button on the form used to save new products.

I can access the "Save" button in the $form array at `$form['actions']['submit']`. However, I'm not seeing the "Save and Continue" button in `$form`.

I looked in commerce_product_ui.module and found the place where this form element is being added. It's called `$form['actions']['save_continue']`. I would expect to see it in the `$form` array, but again - it just doesn't seem to be there.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I know it's not the right way but #edit-save-continue {display:none;} it's the only way i found. I've tried with dsm($page) and I don't find the second button either...

Comment: @Syd Barret, I am interested of this, where you do  dsm($page) - I want to reproduce the situation, for experimental purpose

Comment: Do you want to know where to pur dsm($page)? you should put it in your tpl.php file, it could be page.tpl.php or node.tpl.php or node--CONTENT-TYPE.tlp.php or view.tpl.php

Comment: my question was about this particular situation as it is, because I put dsm() in custom module in _alter or hook_preprocess_ function, and I use commerce module - not Profile commerce kickstart, it does not matter now, it is still useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement hook_form_alter

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { 
  if ($form_id == 'commerce_product_ui_product_form') {
    unset($form['actions']['save_continue']);
  }
}
```

Comment: While I agree this should work, `['save_continue']` does not exist in `$form['actions']` for some reason.

Comment: This answer is technically correct - I just needed to figure out how to alter the form after it was finished being built.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized why this element didn't exist in `$form` at the time.

The Commerce Kickstart module had a higher weight than the module than I wrote, hence it included elements in `$form` after my call to `hook_form_alter()`.

There are two distinct solutions to this:

1.) Increase the [weight of my module](http://drupal.org/node/110238) (to make sure it's called after Commerce Kickstart.)

2.) Optionally, you can add an `#after_build` array to `$form`. This will let you add functions that are called after the form is built.